# Solspace User: submit name with registration

Tags: solspace-user

Can't find this anywhere, but can you let the user submit their first and last name when registering for membership using Solspace User?

Answer (score 1):

I see in the doc where any custom field is support by using the short name. I didn't realize first and last was a custom field and thought it was standard. Must have been created when I install Social Login Pro.